# Why would I bother versioning my files when I can just invalidate the cache every time I deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm pretty sure there is something important I'm missing because AWS says you should version your files to have more control over how they are deployed.

But let's say I'm serving a file called mydumbfile.html. I have my Cloudfront distribution pointed to mydumbfile.html which is in the root of an S3 bucket.

If I ever need to update that file and want the update to get pushed out as quickly as possible I would just update the file in S3 and then run this command to invalidate:
`aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ABC123 --paths "/*"`

What advantages would versioning that file name have here over just manually busting the cache like this for every (infrequent) deploy of changes? Will this cause issues I'm not realizing?

Comment: Very simple reason being able to restore to an earlier version if the latest version is corrupted by human error of deployment process.

Comment: @Ali I dont think thats a valid reason. I can use a versioned s3 bucket, restore a previous file version (with the same name) and bust the cache. Am i missing something?

Comment: hmm perhaps having the version in the file name gives me clearer auditing though. I would be able to tell what version it was just by looking at the name. I wasn't thinking about it that way. If had the same name but different s3 file versions I would need some way of tracking the s3 file version to the actual artifact version